# terminal panel partykit r node id plots object info

Tags: r, binary-tree, party

I'm trying to remove the labels of the Node id's at the terminal panel of a partykit object (those that say Node x...), following the instructions with `terminal_panel`, I can change the `inner_panel` without trouble, but the plot includes information of the object instead of the bars:

```
library(partykit)
ea = ctree(Species ~ ., data = iris)

plot(ea, gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),    
     inner_panel = node_inner,
     ip_args=list(
       abbreviate = F, 
       id = FALSE),
     terminal_panel = node_terminal, 
     tp_args = list(digits = 2, abbreviate = T, id = F))
```

Which plots the following,

[image: l]

Answer (score 3):

I think you can remove some arguments to get your desired output. This code removes the "Node x" label and plots the bars for each terminal node

```
plot(ea,
  gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),
  inner_panel = node_inner,
  ip_args = list(
    abbreviate = F,
    id = FALSE
  ),
  tp_args = list(id = FALSE)
)
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: yes, it worked, removing the terminal panel from the arguments

Comment: You can also add `terminal_panel = node_barplot` again. The problem was that you used `node_terminal` rather than `node_barplot`. The former tries to come up with a textual representation in the terminal nodes that includes all the information stored in the tree. Hence, this looked so messy in plot in the question. BTW: If this solved your problem, please accept that answer so that it gets flagged accordingly here on StackOverflow.